# How to get all divs of a certain class and add innerHTML

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target all divs of a certain class and apply innerHTML. This is what I have, but I'm getting no errors and no result.

```
$( ".programdesc" ).innerHTML( '<p>I am alive</p>' );
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Please accept an answer to let everyone know that your problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Use [the html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) :

```
$( ".programdesc" ).html( '<p>I am alive</p>' );
```

Comment: This is kind of a really nit-picky comment, but this will get all elements with that class, not just `div`s. I would guess that it ends up making no difference in OP's code.

Comment: @ajp15243 Right. OP, if that's a issue for you, use `$('div.programdesc')`. Note that if it's not a problem, it's better (faster) to just have the class in the selector.

Comment: Will this get all elements with that class, even if they have additional classes?

Comment: @miles yes, it would.

Comment: Ah, got it to work (script was in the wrong place, needed to be after the content). However, this method replaces the HTML. I saw the Append method in an answer below and tried that, and voila! Sorry, should have specified I wanted to append html.

Comment: @miles Then use `append` instead of `html`.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("div.programdesc").append('<p>I am alive</p>');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7WjX3/1)

Answer (score 0):

You should use each

```
$( "div.programdesc" ).each(function() {
 (this).innerHTML( '<p>I am alive</p>' );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

`innerHTML` is a property of a DOM Element, not a function.  The property exists in pure Javascript, not in jQuery statements.

```
$(".programdesc").html( 'this is the jQuery way' );

document.getElementsByClassName('programdesc').index(0).innerHTML = "This is the Javascript way";
```

Comment: The second one doesn't work. Live node lists don't have this properties.

Comment: Well, you're definitely right about that, but the OP said nothing about capturing live elements.  If that's the problem, go here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9106397/401299

Comment: *"all divs of a certain class"*

Comment: The word 'certain' connotes something specific....something particular.   `$('.certain')` will catch all particular elements whose class contains certain....Now, if he had said dynamic instead, I would agree with you.

Comment: And JavaScript is definitely not one you know... Just test your code. You'll see that the live list returned by `document.getElementsByClassName` simply doesn't have any `innerHTML`property...