# Attaching event to an object not yet added to DOM

Tags: javascript

I have an `img` object that has NOT yet been appended to the document tree. Is it possible to assign an onclick event (using `attachEvent` or `addEventListener`) to that object? Or do I have to append it to the DOM *first* and *only then* would I be able to attach the event?

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = "image1.png";

// Will any of the following work?
image.attachEvent("onclick", displayImage); // IE
image.addEventListener("click", displayImage, false); // non-IE

document.getElementById("imageDiv").appendChild(image);

function displayImage() {
   ...
}
```

Please, only include pure JavaScript (no JQuery). Thank you!

Comment: What happened when you tried it because I'm sure that would answer your question.

Comment: Your code seems totally accurate, did something broke when you tested it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see you are searching for a native implementation of the jquery live()/on() functionality. You should take a look at [Implementing jQuery's "live" binder with native Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106329/implementing-jquerys-live-binder-with-native-javascript).

Answer (score -1):

what i found：

1. add a judge before use it.
2. getElementById's param needs a "#".

> ```
> var image = document.createElement("img");
> image.src = "image1.png";
> if(image.attachEvent){
> image.attachEvent("onclick", displayImage);} // IE
>
> image.addEventListener("click", displayImage, false); // non-IE
>
> document.getElementById("#imageDiv").appendChild(image);
>
> function displayImage() {
>   ...
> }
> ```