# Unable to attach script files

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, import, single-page-application

### Single Page Application

Tried creating a Single page application. The script files are all imported in `index.html`. They work fine as long as the codes are for the elements in `index.html` file. The subfolder created has a table when I tried to access that id from `subfolder.js` it doesn't work. I tried importing the JavaScript file in both `index.html` and `subfolder.html`, But it doesn't seem to work.

### File structure:

- JavaScript

  - app.js
  - route.js
  - router.js
  - subfolder.js
- Views

  - subfolder.html
- index.html

Where should I import the script file to get and change the element in `subfolder.html` using its id tag.

Comment: SPA (single page app) is running in one html file, what do you mean importing subfolder.html?

Comment: Like we have in frameworks, i used multiple html files without head or body tag and included them in main html file using ajax call.

Comment: you need to add event listeners after render (ajax served html) or use something like jQuery.live() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106329/implementing-jquerys-live-binder-with-native-javascript

Comment: i have added a button click function and it doesn't seem to work. Could you explain. it a little more please.

Comment: Trademark capitalization; grammar.

Comment: `<button onclick="window.namespace.myFunction()">Click me</button>` will definitely work - can't say more without seeing the code ;)